# Any recommendations to help learn a Tosfot in Bava Batra?

Tags: torah-study, adult-learning, tosfot

Which Sefer/Sforim can one use to help when learning a Tosfos in Bava Basra as there is nothing online for this Masechta?

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40323/759

Comment: None of the websites offered in that thread have anything on Bava Basra.

Comment: user8553 So what?

Comment: see metivta in the back

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  If you mean to ask specifically about Bava Basra, you could phrase your question to mean as much.  You can [edit] your question to make it clearer. Otherwise, @DoubleAA is correct that your question is the same as that question.  (Sorry for the pedantry, but things would get out of hand here if we weren't such sticklers.)

Comment: Still a duplicate IMO. The other question is general and includes _BB_. cc @DoubleAA

Answer (score 6):

You can try http://www.dafyomi.co.il/, choose any masechtah, and then scroll down. They have links for Tosafot for most masechtot, but unfortunately not for Bava Basra.

And for books, you can try [this](http://www.mysefer.com/prodtype.asp?PT_ID=543&numRecordPosition=10&strPageHistory=&strKeywords=&strSearchCriteria=) wonderfully clear sefer called שערי תוספות, if you don't mind Hebrew.

Comment: +1 .....I haven't used it in a while, but שערי תוספות is really useful.

Comment: I've lightly edited your answer for increased clarity. If I changed something you didn't want changed, you can always [edit] yourself to fix.